# what version of tsql supports +=

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm working on a script that has a number of `SET @p += 'blah blah'` and it runs fine.
When I'm debugging the script, though, that line wipes out any previous value in @p.

Why does `set @p += 'text here'` work when run but not when debugging?

Versions used

- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2550.0 (X64)
- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2772.0 (X64)

Comment: So is your question about "What version"? Or is it "Why does it?" You've asked two totally separate things here - which one are you asking us to answer for you?

Comment: ? I have never seen any version of SQl use that structure. what on earth are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm modifying the script because it isn't working properly... this is probably why, but I'm surprised that sql even accepted then upon pressing F5.  My question: is there some secret setting that accepts that cause that is in production

Comment: @HLGEM This construct works perfectly in Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 11.0.9214.43

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These operators `+=, -=, *=, /=` etc. where introduced in SQL Server **2008** - see [TechNet documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627392%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) which shows they don't exist before 2008.

Comment: specific link [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd206992%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)... and I swear I and a co-worker googled tsql "+=" and couldn't find that article!